# how to create a function that receives a string "abcbdbd"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
/**
* Let us create a function that receives a string "abcbdbd",
* and returns an array like:
["a", "a.b", "a.b.c", "a.b.c.b", "a.b.c.b.d", "a.b.c.b.d.b", ...]
*/

function splitString(str) {
  const arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.push(str[i]);
    for (var z = 0; z < arr.length; z++) {
      const joinArr = `${arr[0]}.${arr[z]}`;
      console.log(joinArr);
    }
  }

  return [];
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkjj"));
```

how to add . after every string? I have tried for loop. So should I use map and .join?

Comment: Iterate over the characters of the string. `.slice()` the string into pieces that match the required length. `.split()` and `.join(".")`.

Comment: You only ever push one single character into `arr`. The content of `joinArr` is only logged and never stored. `splitString()` always returns an empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using `map`

```js
const str = "abcbdef";

const array = str.split("");

const output = array.map((_, idx, arr) => arr.slice(0, idx + 1).join("."));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array from the string (`Array.from()`), reduce it to an array, so that each element is the current last element (`acc[acc.length-1]`) in the array plus itself. For the first element just add it to the array.

```js
function splitString(str) {
  return Array.from(str).reduce((acc,cv) => {
    if (acc[0]) acc.push(acc[acc.length-1]+"."+cv)
    else acc[0] = cv // if the array is empty, add just the first char
    return acc
  },[])
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkjj"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of all characters and add the last returned value.

```js
function splitString(str) {
    return Array.from(
        str,
        (l => v => l += (l && '.') + v)('')
    );
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkjj"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitString(str) {
  let arr = [];
  let temp = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    temp += (temp !== "" ? "." : "") + str[i];
    arr.push(temp);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(splitString("abcbdbd"));
```